# Vector class implementation using template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am implementing a Vector class using template in C++.
Below is the code that I have written. There are two source files and a header file as shown below:

**Vector.h**:

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
    T *data;
    int vSize;
    int vCapacity;
public:
    Vector();
    ~Vector();
    void PushBack(const T&);
    void PopBack();
    int Size() const;
    int Capacity() const;
    void Reserve(const int&);
    bool Empty() const;
    T& operator[](const int&);
};
```

**Vector.cpp**:

```
#include "Vector.h"
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(){
    data = nullptr;
    vSize = 0;
    vCapacity = 0;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector(){ delete[] data; }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
void Vector<T>::PushBack(const T& val)
{
    if(vSize == vCapacity)
    {
        if(vCapacity == 0)
        {
            Reserve(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Reserve(2 * vCapacity);
        }
    }
    data[vSize] = val;
    vSize++;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
void Vector<T>::PopBack()
{
    vSize--;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
int Vector<T>::Size() const{ return vSize; }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
int Vector<T>::Capacity() const{ return vCapacity; }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
void Vector<T>::Reserve(const int& newCapacity)
{
    T *newData;
    try
    {
        newData = new T[newCapacity];
    }
    catch(...){
        cout << "Memory allocation failure...";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < vSize; i++)
    {
        newData[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;

    data = newData;
    vCapacity = newCapacity;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
bool Vector<T>::Empty() const
{
    return (vSize == 0);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int& offset)
{
    return data[offset];
}
```

**Main.cpp**:

```
#include "Vector.h"
int main()
{
    Vector<int> v;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting below error.

```
||=== Build: Debug in CppApp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\Main.o||In function `main':|
D:\CodeBlocks\CppApp\Main.cpp|5|undefined reference to `Vector<int>::Vector()'|
D:\CodeBlocks\CppApp\Main.cpp|18|undefined reference to `Vector<int>::~Vector()'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|
```

I am unable to understand the error. Request you all to help. I have tried several other attempts to understand it, but failed to do so.
Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: PLEASE search before posting. This is the 3rd time today I've seen this question. :'(

Comment: Rule of thumb: implements all templates in headers

Comment: @ChrisMM Better get used to it. Unfortunately. Most people are not really interested in following the sites guidelines and just want someone to fix their problem.

Comment: @ChrisMM what is wrong with my code? I have also implemented in header file.

Comment: @super I spent several hours in trying to understand the issue. Since, I couldn't get the cause, so posted in this forum.

Comment: You cannot put the template code in the cpp file. Only header. Please read the linked post.

Comment: @PankajKumarThapa Unfortunately you did not spend a few minutes searching for the answer here on SO before posting this question though. Or read any kind of book/tutorial about templates where this for sure would be mentioned.

Comment: https://github.com/pkthapa/Code-Challenges